# How do get an installer to execute?

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install the TI MCDSK and nothing seems to be happening. I downloaded the linux installer: `mcsdk_1_01_00_02_setuplinux.bin` and copied this file into a directory in my linux VM. The permissions for the file were set to execute. When I invoke the file: `./mcsdk< ..>setuplinux.bin`, there are no errors or warnings issued, but nothing happens - it 'executes' - I doubt that's what's happening - in about a second, but there are no directories or files created. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.3 64-bit.